# C#: What am I doing wrong with the textbox?

Tags: c#

[This is what the app looks like so far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1Bxe.jpg) The program is suppose to allow the user to enter a distance, then it'll have a "from" box and a "to" box that will convert the distance to something like "from inches to feet" for example.

When i run the program though the to and from boxes are empty. In the boxes there should be inches, feet, and yards listed. What is wrong in my code here?

```
namespace DistanceConverter
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void convertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int fromDistance;
        int toDistance = 0;

        fromDistance = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        string measureInput = fromBox.Items[fromBox.SelectedIndex].ToString();
        string measureOutput = toBox.Items[toBox.SelectedIndex].ToString();

        switch (measureInput)
        {
            case "Yards":
                switch (measureOutput)
                {
                    case "Inches":
                        toDistance = fromDistance;
                        break;
                    case "Yards":
                        toDistance = fromDistance * 3;
                        break;
                    case "Feet":
                        toDistance = fromDistance * 3 * 12;
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case "Feet":
                switch (measureOutput)
                {
                    case "Inches":
                        toDistance = fromDistance;
                        break;
                    case "Yards":
                        toDistance = fromDistance / 3;
                        break;
                    case "Feet":
                        toDistance = fromDistance * 12;
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case "Inches":
                switch (measureOutput)
                {
                    case "Inches":
                        toDistance = fromDistance;
                        break;
                    case "Feet":
                        toDistance = fromDistance / 12;
                        break;
                    case "Yards":
                        toDistance = fromDistance / (3 * 12);
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }

        distanceConverted.Text = toDistance.ToString();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: How do you populate the to and from boxes? Can you share that code? That appears to be where your problem lies.

Comment: @L0uis I edited the post and included all my code

Comment: How does fromBox.Items get bound?

Comment: Im not following what you mean

Comment: If added from the designer, the source code for populating the combo boxes, list boxes, etc. will be found in the form1.designer.cs file.

Comment: Did you add the items (Inches, Yards, Feet) by using the designer?

Comment: Instead of `fromBox.Items[fromBox.SelectedIndex]` you can use the shorter and readable `fromBox.SelectedItem`.

Comment: "When i run the program though the to and from boxes are empty". The combo boxes need values.

Comment: Please copy/paste your form1.designer.cs. How do you fill those combo boxes?

Comment: Ive updated the post again

Comment: Do you see the little arrow icon on top-right of the toBox ? click that and add the items, each as a line. Do the same for the fromBox

Comment: Oh okay I see now.

Comment: Oh. Good to know :) Good luck.

Comment: Now I'm getting the error CS0079 The event 'ListBox.SelectedIndexChanged' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= DistanceConverter"

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat misleading, looking at the comments I presume that you want to populate the values of you combo boxes,

You can do programmatically from the constructor by adding the items

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Populate fromBox
    fromBox.Items.Add("Inches");
    fromBox.Items.Add("Yards");
    fromBox.Items.Add("Feet");

    // Populate toBox
    toBox.Items.Add("Inches");
    toBox.Items.Add("Yards");
    toBox.Items.Add("Feet");
}
```

or setting a `DataSource`

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var items = new List<string>
    {
        "Inches",
        "Yards",
        "Feet"
    };

    comboBox1.DataSource = items;
    comboBox2.DataSource = items;
}
```

or you can set the values of the `Items` property in the properties panel

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**This is no answer, just some hints in the right direction, cannot post as comment!**

First of all you are doing a lot of unnecessary string comparison. This is bad practice. Check how I use `enum` to populate your comboboxes. Check how I read the selected value from the combobox as well.
Compare how the  button can only be pressed if the value is valid.

You could start using a new C# feature, the switch expression. My few lines are not complete but should give you a hint in the right direction.

````
    {
        double fromValue;

        enum Units
        {
            Inches,
            Yards,
            Feet
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            button1.Enabled = false;
            fromBox.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Units));
            toBox.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Units));
        }


        private double convert(Units from, Units to, double value)
        {
            return (from, to) switch
            {
                (Units.Yards, Units.Inches) => value * 36.0,
                (Units.Yards, Units.Yards) => value,
                //..
            };

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var fromUnit = (Units)fromBox.SelectedItem;
            var toUnit = (Units)toBox.SelectedItem;

            label1.Text = convert(fromUnit, toUnit, fromValue).ToString();
        }



        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Enabled = Double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out fromValue);
        }
    }```
````

Comment: You might have to add the <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion> to your csproj.

Comment: Also be aware the you are doing integer division. that means everything after the comma would be dropped.